# How to install a Symfony 2.0 Bundle from Zip file

Tags: symfony, bundle

I tried installing the FixturesBundle as described in http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html but my proxy wont let me out.

So I went to https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures and download a zip from the latest commit.

I unzipped into the vendor directory and renamed it to *doctrine-fixures*. I edited the autoload.php and AppKernel.php files as described in the tutorial.

When I run:

```
php app\console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

I get the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesB
undle' not found in C:\NetbeansProjects\route_rest_service\app\AppKernel.php on
line 20

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle
' not found in C:\NetbeansProjects\route_rest_service\app\AppKernel.php on line
20
```

Is there a way to run the installation of bundle pointing it to a zip file?

I´m running Symfony 2.0.9 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the doctrine bundle has been moved outside of Symfony scope back to Doctrine.

Please, use https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle

Comment: Thanks Felix. After reading https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst I realized I had not download the DoctrineFixturesBundle. I downloaded it as zip and unzipped it in vendor\bundles\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle. It still cannot find the 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixtures
Bundle'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true that Doctrine is being moved away from the Symfony namespace (see [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/symfony-bundles-move)).

So if you're using the Symfony standard distribution you download from the website (without using git), and you want to have the `FixturesBundle` installed manually, you have to download the doctrine-fixtures library from [here](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures), extract the zip into

```
YourProject/vendor/doctrine-fixtures
```

Download the `FixturesBundle` from [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle), and extract it in

```
YourProject/vendor/bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle
```

Then you have to register the library's namespace, do it by adding

```
'Doctrine\\\\Common\\\\DataFixtures' => \__DIR\__.'/../vendor/doctrine-fixtures/lib',
```

in your `autoload.php`.

In addition, you'll have to register the Doctrine's namespace, because some part of your application will be using the `DoctrineBundle` shipped from the Symfony namespace, but the new downloaded `FixturesBundle` will be using the new Doctrine's namespace, so to make it work, in your `autoload.php` add the following line (taking care you do it *before* the Doctrine namespace, remember that more specific rules go first!)

```
'Doctrine\\\\Bundle' => \__DIR\__.'/../vendor/bundles',
```

So all you have to do now is to register the new bundle in your `AppKernel.php` writing

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is how i successfully solved it. I started to download this files [data-fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) and [DoctrineFixturesBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle), unzipped both into `/vendor/doctrine` and created this folder structure:

```
vendor
  - doctrine
    - doctrine-fixtures-bundle
      - Doctrine
        - Bundle
         - FixturesBundle
           DoctrineFixturesBundle.php
           ..other files...


vendor
  - doctrine
    - data-fixtures
      - lib
      - test
      composer.json
      ..other files...
```

Then i edited the `AppKernel.php` and added

```
public function registerBundles(){
  .....
  new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
  .....
}
```

Edited the `composer.json` located in the root of the project and added this 2 lines:

```
"Doctrine\\Bundle\\FixturesBundle": "vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle",
"Doctrine\\Common\\DataFixtures": "vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib"
```

Mine, now look like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "": "src/",
            "Doctrine\\Bundle\\FixturesBundle": "vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle",
            "Doctrine\\Common\\DataFixtures": "vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib"
        }
    }
}
```

afterwards execute `composer dump-autoload -o` to recreate the classmap. All this was thanks to the users [Wouter J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149495/wouter-j) and [nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) that answered my question [How to install DoctrineFixturesBundle offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598669/how-to-install-doctrinefixturesbundle-offline)

Happy coding!