# How to install DoctrineFixturesBundle offline

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

First of all, i can't use composer because of my ISP, so, i need a way to install the `DoctrineFixturesBundle` manually, so i started downloading it from `github`, also the `data-fixtures` bundle. 
i create this folder structure in my project

```
vendor
  - doctrine
    - doctrine-fixtures-bundle
      - Doctrine
        - Bundle
         - FixturesBundle
           DoctrineFixturesBundle.php
           ..other files...


vendor
  - doctrine
    - data-fixtures
      - lib
      - test
      composer.json
      ..other files...
```

i did this by reading the composer.json file located within each bundle, then i edited the `AppKernel.php` and added

```
public function registerBundles(){
  .....
  new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
  .....
}
```

but it is not working, i always get:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not 
 found in D:\wamp\www\cupon\app\AppKernel.php on line 20
```

Am i missing something? can i install those bundles manually?
Hope you can help me.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to setup the autoloading in your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Doctrine\\Bundle\\FixturesBundle": "vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle",
            "Doctrine\\Common\\DataFixtures": "vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib",
        }
    }
}
```

Composer does this automatically on `composer update`, but as you didn't install the packages using composer, this wasn't done for these packages.

Comment: Hehe you were quicker than me ... i was still typing. Answer should work - afterwards execute `composer dump-autoload -o` - other solution not requiring any changes to composer.json would be temporarily moving the `Doctrine` folders to `src/`

Comment: there are a lots of `composer.json` in symfony2, where is located the one you are talking about? sorry, lol

Comment: He is talking about the one located in your project's root folder. Your main dependency file - the other files are the ones provided by the packages themselves.

Comment: Now it is working!!!!! after i made the changes suggested by @Wouter J, i tried and didn't work, so, i run `composer dump-autoload -o` suggested by @nifr and even when i don't know what it does, now everything is working like a charm, thanks

Comment: The command will recreate the classmap telling the autoloader where to find your classes aka `vendor/autoload.php` and the files in the `vendor/composer` folder :) Happy coding!