# DoctrineFixturesBundle manually install

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle

I'm new in S2 and I got a problem in my hands. My ISP deny recursive DNS consults and for that reason I can't use composer.

I download via web Symfony 2.3.25, DoctrineFixturesBundle and DataFixtures, next install LAMP-SERVER, create a VHOST looking to my S2 project, configure database and all the S2 requisites.

Until here all is ok, I create mi first bundle, for my application. But now I need to charge the DB with some initial data.

Uncompress DoctrineFixturesBundle-master.zip in vendor/doctrine and rename the folder to doctrine-fixtures-bundle and uncompress data-fixtures-master.zip in the same localtion, changing the folder name to data-fixtures like said in http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Next I update the AppKernel.php with $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();

Now for test I run "php app/console" to but I got an error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /var/www/bidem2/app/AppKernel.php on line 27

Is necesary another configuration??? I missing some tool instalation??? I really know that composer is the adecuate way but I can't use this tool, please help me...

Comment: You could run composer install on another machine and upload the main application files along with the resulting vendor map to your server.

Comment: in my prj the bundle is located in the `<project-home>/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle`folder. BTW you must manually donwload and setup the bundle dependency (as described in the composer.json of the fixture-bundle) so is better you can adopt a different deploy strategy for setup the vendor on another machine. Hope this help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598669/how-to-install-doctrinefixturesbundle-offline

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you didn't set up autoload. Composer have own autoload implementation. But you need to set composer's autoload manually or do it like it was in Symfony 2.1 before composer.